# 8086 Assembly interrupts for reading/writing binary to/from files?

Tags: file, assembly, io, x86-16

I need to read in about 1KB or so of data at a time, manipulate it, and write it to another file. I need to do this for at least 100 MB. I have never done any file IO in assembly before.

What interrupts do I need to call and what needs to be in what registers?

Comment: Well my laptop is Windows 7, but I'm targeting x86 processors. I've found one tutorial for reading in a file here: 

http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2720.htm

This works on my machine but I'm hoping to have a better understanding and not just cut and paste this code...

Comment: That code is using function 09h of interrupt 21h (the DOS interrupt), see http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm (from Ralf Brown's Interrupt List) for parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please specify the OS you're targeting. For DOS, google for Ralf Brown's Interrupt List. For linux, look for asm/unistd.h.